# Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

When I build a GoogleMaps SDK for iOS,these error occurred.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources''
```

but,GoogleMaps.framework is in copy bundle resources.so,I'm confused.please tell me cause of this problem.

Comment: After adding GoogleMaps.bundle in GoogleMaps.framework to my copy bundle resource,all go well !! Thank you !!

Comment: Just clean and run. It'll be work

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The instructions are kinda lacking.

1. Launch Xcode (easy)
2. Drag the GoogleMaps.framework bundle to the Frameworks
   group of your project. When prompted, ***select Copy items*** into
   destination group's folder.
3. Right-click GoogleMaps.framework in your project, and select Show In
   Finder.  ***What it doesn't say is...Then go into the child folder called Resources***
4. Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle from the Resources folder to your
   project. We suggest putting it in the Frameworks group. When
   prompted, ***ensure Copy items into destination group’s folder is not
   selected.***

Comment: This is better instructions than mine ! Thank you !

Comment: Glad to hear it - were you able to get an API key that made the mapping work?

Comment: yep,but It took me a month to take an API key X(

Comment: Your additions here are now reflected in the official docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#obtaining_an_api_key

Perhaps someone at Google saw this post?

Comment: I did this , my app crashes still

Comment: Where is this child folder?

Comment: I did this , my app crashes still and dosent seems there is a frameworks folder in Xcode 7 any more.

Comment: Still having the same problem :(

Comment: As said by @JohnyDgoode, after adding GoogleMaps.bundle in GoogleMaps.framework to my copy bundle resource, all went well!

Comment: Saved me 2 days !! This is what good documentation should have said on the first place! Anyhow, cheers !

Comment: And also `libz.tbd` and `libc++.tbd` is needed to add to `Link Binary With Library` section. [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_2_install_the_sdk).

Answer (score 89):

To the 2017 people searching on SO, the easiest way is indeed try the installing and updating your pod by of course `pod install` and `pod update`. Then finally, clean the project and the build by these two commands:

1. Clean Build: `Command + alt option + Shift + K`
2. Clean Project: `Command + Shift + K`

Then voila! Crash won't happen again.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks myself! Happened to me again in Xcode 9.0 beta 2.

Comment: Also, clear derived data. Seems to help. xCode -> Preferences -> Locations  then click the little arrow next to the derived data path. Move the folder that pops up in finder to the trash.

Comment: @Glenn After every time I make the change in storyboard and change its localized text. Map crashes. Is there any solution?

Comment: @nikdange_me Hmm not sure, but have you tried this answer? Just clean your project everytime you change your localized text? OR perhaps post a new question.

Comment: @Glenn I tried your answer, it works. I have to do it every time I change storyboard and localize its text. I have to do 'pod install' n 'update'. Is there any solution to fix it *once*? btw thanks. :)

Comment: Yes it helps, but after a while this error is repeated again.

Answer (score 8):

If you are experiencing this issue in a more recent version of this framework and are using the CocoaPods deployment, then check that the "*Copy Pods Resources*" section of "*Build Phases*":

[image]

Apparently this section going missing is a thing and deleting your Pods directory and re-running "*pod install*" isn't sufficient to fix it. Instead you will need to grab [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) handy tool:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Run this thing and then re run *pod install* and your "*Copy Pods Resources*" section should be back and you won't get this exception when you instantiate your map.

Comment: i already have this section in Build phases, but map is sill not working

Comment: Sorry @sandeeptomar I guess your problem must be something else.

Comment: Copy Pods Resources can go missing indeed, and pod reintegrate didn't fix it for me. I created a new project, did a pod install with the relevant pod, then copied the pod resources script over 

Comment: Thanks @RedBlueThing. my problem is resolved with this trick. I could see "Copy Pods Resources" section again. deintegrate is a great tool. thanks

Answer (score 7):

For those of you trying this out in 2017 with Xcode 9 (first release) and the new build system, the following resolved this for me.

Note: The fundamental issue seems to be that the new build system is NOT cleaning properly, so you need to switch back to the old system. Also as of 9/25/17 the google place picker is calling UI off the main thread and is throwing errors in Xcode.

-Switch to old build system

-click your project file "My App Name"

-Under "TARGETS" click your app name (not tests or UITests!)

-build phases

-[CP] Copy Pods Resources

-You should see ${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleSomething , select those and hit -

-Close Xcode, run pod install.

-Open Xcode, Command-Shift-K (clean, and MAKE SURE YOU'RE ON THE OLD BUILD SYSTEM!)

-Build/Run, should work now

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me out of all the other answers

Answer (score 4):

running "pod install" fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you installed the map via CocoaPods Try the following steps.

1. Go to TARGETS > Build Phases
2. Disable 'Run script only when installing'
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

For Me i have the same issue in the manual installation.

1.right-click GoogleMaps.framework in your project, and select Show In Finder .

1. double click or Open this GoogleMaps.framework. we can able to see the Folder "Resources" . (i have added the image Screen Shot for the where GoogleMaps.bundle available)
2. click the Resources folder we can find the GoogleMaps.bundle

[image]

3. now just Drag and Drop the GoogleMaps.bundle into your project. ensure Copy items into destination group’s folder is not selected.
   [image]

Note: ensure "Copy items if Needed" destination group’s folder is not selected. see the Screen shot too.

now Clean the Command+Shift+K or Xcode-->Product--> Clean

this may helps to someone.

Comment: What do you mean by "track into your project"?

Comment: sorry @FARID this is "drag and drop" into your project

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue, do the following:

```
1. Go to derived folder and delete the project folder
2. Clean build and run
```

Fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources'

1. find `GoogleMaps.bundle` in `GoogleMap.frameword/Resources` you will see GoogleMap.bundle
2. Drag `GoogleMaps.bundle` into `Base/Framework` with GoogleMapsBase.framework

hope this can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once I updated to Xcode 9 Swift 3.2 I kept getting a crash inside AppDelegate at this line:

```
GMSServices.openSourceLicenseInfo()
```

I kept using Glenn's answer to clean the project which definitely worked but eventually the crash kept happening.

To solve it I had to follow the directions in [Google Maps API Installation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#obtaining_an_api_key)

Follow:

*Step 2: Install the SDK* and **Install Manually**

**This is very easy to do but 1 thing sort of confused me at first so I'm adding it in for clarity for the next person:**

Once your read the manual instructions and on number 4 it says:

```
4. Drag the following bundles into your project (when prompted, select Copy items if needed):
```

[image]

The thing is inside the zip file that you download, once you unpack it there are only going be 2 frameworks inside of it:

```
GoogleMaps.framework
GoogleMapsCore.framework
```

There won't be a `GoogleMapsBase.framework`. I'm assuming they bundled it into the `GoogleMaps.framework`?

Once you get to number `8: Open the Build Phases tab, and within Link Binary with Libraries, add the following frameworks:`. It lists a number of frameworks that you have to import.

[image]

The problem is the first 3 that are listed that it says to add were already added (actually two of them were added -`GoogleMaps.framework` and `GoogleMapsCore.framework`) when you unpacked that zip file and dragged them into your project.

I kept typing in the names and nothing would show up.

[image]

I kept deleting all the Google frameworks, starting from the beginning, and trying again until I realized they already existed. Basically type in the names of everything from `Accelerate.framework` - `UIKit.framework` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

**This way I have fixed my issue.**

```
 1. Delete the derived folder.
 2. pod update
 3. Clean Project and build.
```

Thats all