# GMSService exception Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle

Tags: ios, google-maps, mono, xamarin.ios

Similar problem to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744479/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-requires-googlemaps-bundle-to-be-part-of-your-target-und).

My app crashes as soon as I try to load any view controller that has an embedded Google Map - the error I receive is the following:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources''

I'm using Monotouch with Google Map bindings from:
https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleMaps

This used to work just fine in my application - I'm not sure what exactly I changed but now my app crashes.

**It's also worth noting that the crash only occurs on the device - everyone runs perfectly fine in the iOS simulator.**

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the new Xamarin Studio has support for components and adding the Google Maps component to your app from that route solves the issue... oh well.