# Debug error xcode 6- using google maps sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, xcode6

I was testing my app and whenever I try to open a view that uses maps the app terminates and this error appears

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSBundle initWithURL:]:
>   nil URL argument'

I wrote my code like this:

```
   CGRect s = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-50);

    GMSCameraPosition *theCamera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                             longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
                                                                  zoom:18];


    self.mapView= [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:s camera:theCamera];
```

This is how I,m initialising the map.

This is the complete error message in the console:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSBundle initWithURL:]:
>   nil URL argument'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x187e52084 0x1984300e4 0x187e51fc4 0x188cadc08 0x188cadb84 0x100377ba8 0x100377b28 0x1003a8dc8
>   0x100aa4ee0 0x100aa5dec 0x1003a8bb8 0x1003a638c 0x1003a62b4
>   0x1003a6d18 0x10039f330 0x10039ecb8 0x10039eb50 0x1001957dc
>   0x18c5d4ccc 0x18c5d49dc 0x18ccc0644 0x18c8ce674 0x18c8e9588
>   0x18c8eb99c 0x18c6c1c88 0x1001adc64 0x18c608e68 0x18c5f1fc0
>   0x18c608804 0x18c608490 0x18c6019e4 0x18c5d51d4 0x18c87398c
>   0x18c5d373c 0x187e0a324 0x187e095c8 0x187e07678 0x187d35664
>   0x190e775a4 0x18c63a4f8 0x100081c00 0x198a9ea08) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add GoogleMaps.bundle to your project's Frameworks.
You can find it in GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Resources. and make sure that the "Copy items if needed" is not checked

you can also try the solution suggested here:
[Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744479/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-requires-googlemaps-bundle-to-be-part-of-your-target-und)