# GMSGeocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate throws fatal error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-geocoder, reversegeocodelocation

When I try to reverse a coordinate which is [somewhere in the South Atlantic Ocean](https://www.google.com.tr/maps/place/33%C2%B043'27.6%22S+15%C2%B059'45.9%22W/@-33.7239823,-23.8825811,5.18z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-33.72434!4d-15.996094?hl=tr),

```
let geocoder = GMSGeocoder.init()
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(
    latitude: -33.724339999999998, 
    longitude: -15.996094000000001)

geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { (response, error) in 
  print(response)
})
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Yes, I don't expect a response but it shouldn't fail with a fatal error, am I right?

Is that a normal behaviour for [GMSGeocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder)?

Answer (score 0):

```
geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) {(response, error) in 

    if((response?) != nil){
        print(response)
    }

})
```

Comment: Hi, please could you explain your code? Code only answers might get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

So I've experienced this weird crash as well while using reverse geocode of Google Map and since you haven't neither chosen a correct answer nor posted your own solution. I checked the production build of my app (From App Store) is working fine. I did try stashing my changes just to check what crap I did that causes this crash.

The log also states something like this:

> Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target

Now for the solution, I have posted it too here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45607775/3231194

Basically just try to update your pods and clean the project and the build, then you're good to go.