# How to add google map direction API in ios Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've ran into a couple of issues with some of the code I've wrote for using Google map direction in our application. I've got this error when running our app.
[I have gone through this link and get this error on load the mapview.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)

[image]

Comment: Looks like you did not make step 7.

Comment: @OMGHaveFun I have already completed all steps.

Comment: Did you added framework by using pods or manually?

Comment: @Himanth manually.

Comment: Try to deleting the contents of the folder "derived data" and rebuild all.

Comment: Also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744479/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-requires-googlemaps-bundle-to-be-part-of-your-target-und

Comment: @Mukesh Did you solved your problem?

Comment: @Himanth yes. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `GoogleMaps.bundle` to your project.

You can find it in your downloaded framework

> GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Resources

Make sure that the "Copy items if needed" is not checked.

Comment: can you help me out to show route direction in map?

Comment: we can show route by using gmspath if you have coordinates