# AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-react

I am facing this issue which I believe a lot of other people are facing after some searching. I am trying to install Google maps IOS SDK manually rather than pods approach. Any solution pertaining to pods does not work for me. I am able to render the map but when I provide "provider google" it throws me the error. I need to have the google maps rather than the apple maps.
What I have done so far:

**My package.json snippet:**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"   
 },   
 "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.2.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
```

I am following this documentation which I think is quite accurate other than some small tweaks.

My react native component which renders maps.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { ScrollView, View } from 'react-native'
import styles from './style'
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps'

class Location extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
          style={styles.map}
          region={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          }}
        >
        </MapView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

My Xcode File hierarchy:

[image]

Libraries linked:

[image]

Also, I have included the paths in header search in build settings. Also, I have included AirMaps.xcodeproj under my libraries in Xcode. I have seen more solutions with Podfile but I am curious If somebody has manually done it by resolving this error. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally what I was missing has been found here: [Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744479/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-requires-googlemaps-bundle-to-be-part-of-your-target-und)

So what I did is in Steps For installing the react-native:

1. `npm install --save react-native-maps`
2. `react-native link react-native-maps`
3. Download the google maps ios SDK from here 
   [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start
4. Follow the steps for manually installing the ios SDK, In the 4th
   Step of google documentation

   Drag the following bundles into your project under Frameworks in
   Xcode (when prompted, select Copy items if needed):

   - GoogleMaps-2.7.0/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework
   - GoogleMaps-2.7.0/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework
   - GoogleMaps-2.7.0/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework
5. Right-click GoogleMaps.framework in your project, and select Show In
   Finder. What it doesn't say is...Then go into the child folder
   called Resources
6. Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle from the Resources folder to your
   project. We suggest putting it in the under the Frameworks folder in
   Xcode. **When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group’s
   folder is not selected.**
7. Go to  Build Settings in Xcode for your project and type "Header
   Search Paths" in the search bar and double click the debug to see
   the header search paths in debug build. Click + to add the path and
   add "$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/" with the recursive option.
8. Go to Build Phases of your project in Xcode. Add the following
   frameworks and libraries.

   - GoogleMapsBase.framework
   - GoogleMaps.framework
   - GoogleMapsCore.framework
   - libAirMaps.a
     **Note:** In case libAirMaps.a does not get linked automatically then you can link manually by dragging the AirMaps.xcodeproj from
     node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios to the Libraries folder on
     k/start

Hope so it helps anyone :)

Comment: Thanks, the only working description I found. To enable Google Maps without Google Maps iOS Utils, I also had to patch out a few things in react-native-maps, maybe that helps someone: https://gist.github.com/devattendant/873e83bd84aba557491498bd850a224c