# flutter can't build with Xcode11.3

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

After updating xcode, I cannot build flutter code with xcode.

Each tools are
xcode version is 11.3
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable
Dart 2.7.0

And log is following.
How can I solve it?

```
...

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.fr
    amework/Headers/CoreMedia.h:15:10: note: in file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.fr
    amework/Headers/CoreMedia.h:15:
    #include <CoreMedia/CMFormatDescription.h>
             ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.fr
    amework/Headers/CMFormatDescription.h:26:10: error: could not build module 'CoreAudio'
    #include <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>
             ^
    /Users/naohide_a/Workspace/flutter/sample/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: note: in file included from
    /Users/naohide_a/Workspace/flutter/sample/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:
    #import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
            ^
    /Users/naohide_a/Workspace/flutter/sample/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:9: error: could not build module 'Flutter'
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^
    192 errors generated.
    <unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header
    '/Users/naohide_a/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gfrbptjupluobbdhelljevlsxpqy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-He
    ader-swift_16EJIZIOPB8S-clang_KLU4EDN5EN1U.pch' for bridging header '/Users/naohide_a/Workspace/flutter/sample/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
    <unknown>:0: error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45607775/3231194

Comment: @Glenn I just built default sample app. it doesn't have podfile yet.

Comment: did you try to run a `flutter clean`?

Comment: @patreu22 yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

I degraded flutter to v1.12.13+hotfix.6 and xcode to 11.2.1.
And finally worked fine for me.

Comment: How did you do that?